# Odoo: ¿Cómo saber quien instalo un módulo?

Tags: odoo

Hace unos días me percate que hay un módulo de mas en un entorno de producción (este módulo no fue comprado como los otros) en Odoo-11 para Odoo.sh, entonces deseaba saber si existe alguna forma de determinar quien fue el usuario que instalo el módulo.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Realicé la misma pregunta en el sitio de StackOverflow pero en inglés y me ofrecieron una respuesta que puede ser la que este necesitando.

Dejo el enlace a la pregunta:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54809460/odoo-how-to-know-who-installed-a-specific-module.

Comment: De todas formas si la misma no funciona estaré dejando algunos comentarios.